# I am not able to Scroll in appium

Tags: appium, chrome-custom-tabs, appium-android, appium-desktop

I have tried multiple options to scroll through the page of custom chrome tab application built as an android app for a tablet, I am still not able to.

Touch action code from appium desktop does not run in eclipse IDE.
and UiScrollable is not able to locate .

It would be great if anybody could help me with this or tell me if it is because of chrome custom tab limitation which has to be treated as a browser and not as an android app for automation.

Comment: What you have tried, could you please share with us?

Comment: Hi, I have used touch actions and now it is able to work when i have used thread.sleep before and after the touch actions command.